# How to execute an interactive multiline bash script remotely over ssh which has default csh shell?

Tags: bash, ssh, csh

I'm writing a script that would give me an ability to execute other local bash scripts remotely over SSH without uploading them. Some of my servers have Linux, some FreeBSD with csh as default. So far, I've came to the following:

```
ssh remote_server 'bash -c '\'"$(cat local_script.sh)"\'' script_parameters'
```

This allows me to execute local_script.sh on remote_server, supports interactivity (for example, "read" command will work in local_script.sh), and I can transfer positional parameters to the script. The problem is that if a local_script.sh has multiple lines the code above works for remote servers with bash default shell only. On FreeBSD sshd starts csh first to execute "bash -c" command and tries to pass the script code (the result of $(cat local_script.sh)) to it as the first parameter. But because this code is multiline and csh wants the closing quote be on the same line as the opening quote I get the "Unmatched '." error. So csh just can't parse this escaped multiline parameter to pass it to the bash process.

The only solution I can see now is to parse the local_script.sh and automatically rewrite it into a one-liner using ";" delimiters before passing it via SSH. But this requires creating another script and seems to be not so easy. So I'd like to ask if this csh miltiline parsing problem can be resolved somehow?

Answer (score 1):

What about using standard input `/dev/stdin` ?

```
ssh remote_server bash /dev/stdin script_parameters < local_script.sh
```

Using two different commands and temporary file

bash

```
ssh remote_server $'tmp=`mktemp tmp.XXXXXX`;cat <<\'HEREDOC_END\' >"$tmp"
'"$(cat local_script.sh)"'
HEREDOC_END
bash "$tmp" script_parameters ;rm "$tmp"'
```

csh

```
ssh remote_server 'set tmp=`mktemp tmp.XXXXXX`;cat <<"HEREDOC_END" >"$tmp"
'"$(cat local_script.sh)"'
"HEREDOC_END"
bash "$tmp" script_parameters ;rm "$tmp"'
```

Comment: This will disable interactivity. Commands like "read" get their input from stdin. If I use stdin for code "read" would consider code lines as its input. I need "read" to take input from a user, so stdin is not an option.

Comment: ok, i misread the question, otherwise maybe using here-doc, updating answer but i can't test

Comment: after reading again the question and as the command should work with csh and bash default shell both it seems difficult to have one command working on both cases. Also note that local_script.sh can't use signle quotes otherwise bash solution will break.

Comment: This will be pretty much the same as copying the script file to a server with scp and executing it via SSH after that. But I think you are right with this approach, maybe I just over-complicate things. I didn't want to copy script file to a server to exclude manual work, but I can do copying, execution and script removing with another simple script, no need for fancy tricks. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, there is no need to keep the outermost quotes.

```
ssh remote_server bash -c "\"$(cat local_script.sh)\"" script_parameters
```

This is not entirely robust; for example, single quotes in `local_script.sh` will not quote text verbatim.  So the following example

```
echo 'fnord "$(echo yes)"'
```

will have the command substitution evaluated remotely even though the string is in single quotes.  In the general case, you'd have to replace `cat` with, basically, a shell parser which identifies constructs which need escaping.

Comment: You are right, the outermost quotes are not necessary here. And thanks for the comment about singe quotes inside local_script.sh. I did my tests with simple scripts and hadn't run into this problem, it has to be sorted out later. Unfortunately, this is not the main problem here, I still have to figure our how to get past csh with multiline parameter.